# How to use page jumps to top of banner and page title?

Tags: permalinks, pages, links, troubleshooting, references

I've tried using page jumps as instructed by countless websites to "jump to the top of my page":

Source code followed by destination code:

```
<a href="top_page">LINK TEXT HERE</a> 
<a id="top_page"></a>
```

However, this process only takes me to the top of the "body" portion of my page. **Is there a way to jump to the *very* top of the *whole* page (i.e., above the title and banner picture)?** In other words, I want to be able to jump so the scroll bar is up the whole way .

---

(Obviously I could just re-input the whole page's url, but that would essentially be a page reload, not simply moving to the top of the page. Is there no other way?).

Answer (score 1):

Just link to `#`. That will automatically take you to the top of the page.

You can test it on this page by clicking [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253846/how-to-use-page-jumps-to-top-of-banner-and-page-title#).

> I've tried using page jumps as instructed by countless websites to "jump to the top of my page":

Curious. Why are they instructing you to do this?